# Missing shortcut options in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I've noticed that I'm no longer able to use shortcuts like `Alt-IR` and `Alt-IC` to insert rows and columns. I'm sure I used to be able to on this machine but recently it doesn't work any more.

How do I get these shortcuts back?

Comment: Does anything else get triggered instead with Alt+I? Do you have any app running that could have set a global shortcut for that key combination?

Comment: No, nothing else gets triggered (just a "ding" error noise) and it happens even when Excel is the only thing running.

Comment: So even with Excel closed pressing Alt+I makes an error noise?

Comment: Only if there is something else open which doesn't have an Alt+I shortcut. On the desktop it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, those shortcuts don't work anymore, no idea, why.

However, instead

1. *Select row*: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> or *Select column*: <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>
2. *Insert*:<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S+</kbd>)

will also do the job almost as quick.

The good thing about this approach is that you can vary it depending on your needs, e.g.

- To delete row/column: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd> as second step
- To insert multiple columns/rows: use <kbd>Shift</kbd> and arrow keys after step 1 to enhance selection
- To move/copy rows columns: select columns/rows to move as in step 1 and step above, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, then proceed with step 1. & 2. in the new target range

Comment: As I said, they worked for me too then stopped. These other shortuts are useful but don't answer the question.